# Makefile that recompiles only if its dependency actually changed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's imagine that I have a file that is generated based not on some other file in the file system, but some external command whose output may or may not change. Can I express this concept in the makefile and have dependent targets only run if the content actually changed?

To specific, I have a file `date.h` which has the current date, hour and minute (but not seconds), which is generated by a rule like this:

```
echo "#define DATE" '"' $$(date '+%D-%H:%M') '"' > date.h
```

The default 'app' target depends on `date.h` and the whole Makefile looks like:

```
app: date.h
    echo "Building app"
    touch app

date.h: FORCE
    echo "#define DATE" '"' $$(date '+%D-%H:%M') '"' > date.h

FORCE:
```

Now the `FORCE` target causes `date.h` to be rebuild every time, which causes `app` to always be out of date and get rebuilt.

On the other hand, if I don't include the `FORCE` target, then `date.h` will only be rebuilt if it doesn't exist (e.g., after a clean or after initially cloning the project), but never again after that.

What I want is for date.h to be out of date only if its contents were actually changed by the `echo` - that is, when the minute changes, but not otherwise. Is there some way to tell make to only consider `date.h` changed if its actual bytes changed on disk, rather than going by the timestamp, or another way to achieve this effect?

Echoing the date to a temporary file and then conditionally updating `date.h` based on comparing their contents crossed my mind, but I'm not sure if it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: That last sentence sounds like a reasonable approach to me. You must execute `echo` every time, and Make looks at file modification times, not contents, so if you want to use Make I think you must do something like that.

Comment: The usual approach is like you describe. Generate the file as temporary file, check to see if it changed, if so replace the target with the temporary file. GCC has a `move-if-change` script exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Might I suggest that having a changing item like the time-of-day in a string/file/build is a bug in and of itself. You should use a version tag instead. Whenever something changes, the version tag changes. And poof! Suddenly this becomes a non-issue and your Makefile can be small and sexy without the contortions you currently ponder.

Comment: @Jens - in fact the primary use-case is for a version tag. The same general issue remains: how to update the version tag in an incremental way. Note that the version may change w/o any dependency changing (e.g., changing branches, update to a README) and vice-versa (local edits).

Comment: @RossRidge and @Beta - I had mistakenly understood that if `date.h` dependencies were out of date, the dependents of `date.h` would be rebuilt even if if date.h wasn't updated (i.e., out-of-dateness is transitive) but I see that's not the case: if the rule for `date.h` runs but doesn't result in `date.h` being updated then the `app` rule doesn't run. That makes it easier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggested doing in your last paragraph is the usual way of conditionally rebuilding targets only if a particular dependency has actually changed, rather than just if that dependency's time stamp has changed. In the rule that generates the particular dependency, you generate it as a temporary file, check to see if its contents have changed and if so replace the target of the rule with the temporary file. Notably, GCC has been doing this in its makefiles as long as I can remember. It generates source code and header files with things like tables and pattern recognizers that often don't change when one of their dependencies does. Stopping targets that are dependants of these generated files from being rebuilt can make a big difference in build times.

So for your example makefile you could do something like:

```
date.h: FORCE
        echo "#define DATE" '"' $$(date '+%D-%H:%M') '"' > date.h.tmp
        if test -r date.h;                                              \
        then                                                            \
                cmp date.h.tmp date.h || mv -f date.h.tmp date.h;       \
        else                                                            \
                mv date.h.tmp date.h;                                   \
        fi
```

You might also want to look using at the `move-if-change` shell script included in the GCC source.

Comment: Might want to remove date.h.tmp when they compare equal

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, how to possibly solve this problem. The idea is this: You check for a temporary file, which is saved with date and time values. So, for the first time, you get a file like `tmp/YYMMDDHHMM`. When you run you `Makefile` again, then it is checked, if this files exists. If yes, do not create a new / do not update `date.h`. After a minute, if you run your `Makefile` again, a new file `tmp/YYMMDDHHMM` is generated and so `date.h` is updated:

```
TMP_DIR := tmp
RUN_OR_NOT := $(shell date '+%y%m%d%H%M')

all: ${TMP_DIR}/date.h

tmp_dir:
        mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR}

${TMP_DIR}/${RUN_OR_NOT}: tmp_dir
        if [ ! -f "${TMP_DIR}/${RUN_OR_NOT}" ]; then \
                echo "" > ${TMP_DIR}/${RUN_OR_NOT}; \
        fi;

${TMP_DIR}/date.h: ${TMP_DIR}/${RUN_OR_NOT}
        # create date.h
        @echo "Run date.h target, which creates date.h"
        touch ${TMP_DIR}/date.h

.PHONY: all special
```